# how to know if a certain resource exist?

Tags: php

For instance, I want to know if these files exists.

```
http://www.stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico
http://www.stackoverflow.com/reset.css
```

and then download it ( if exixts obviously ).

Comment: Try to download, and if it fails they don't exist?

Comment: You'll get a 404 response when the files don't exist. Check for that.

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is to make a cURL NOBODY request just to fetch the headers.. you'll know it exists at that point and can then request the full resource. However, if you're going to download the whole thing anyway you might as well just use `file_get_contents()` and check the results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php

if( ( $file = file_get_contents( 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico' ) ) ) {
    echo "file exists.";
    file_put_contents( 'favicon.ico', $file );
}
else {
    echo "File does not exist.";
}
```

Comment: +1 One note: `file_get_contents()` will generate an E_WARNING error if the request fails. This might be one of those cases where the error suppression operator can be used since the intent is to catch those failures by return type.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();

$url    = 'YOUR_URL_HERE'; // the url you want to check

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_USER_AGENT' ] );

// make "HEAD" request
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true );

$res    = curl_exec( $ch );
$res    = explode( ' ', substr( $res, 0, strpos( $res, "\n" ) ) );

// if 404, file does not exist
if( $res[ 1 ] != 404 ) {
    $file = file_get_contents( $url ); 
} else {
    // This url does not exist
    $file = '';
}

curl_close( $ch );
?>
```

Hope this helps.