# How to save this string in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

When I save this string in PHP:

```
John: "Yes you can".
```

In my database is saved as:

```
John: \
```

How can I save these strings with " ( without deleting " obviously ).
This is my php code:

```
$titlepost= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
$query = "INSERT INTO `titles` (`title`) VALUES ( '".$titlepost."')";
$res = mysql_query($query) or die("Failed".mysql_error() );

echo $titlepost;

output: 
John: \\
```

FORM:

```
$title = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['title']);

<form method="post" action="title.php?done=yes" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" size="25" name="title" <?php echo "value=\"".$title."\""; ?> > 
<input id="starit" name="submit" value="titleit" type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Try to use addslashes function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php

Comment: @yen1k: **Certainly NOT!** `mysql_real_escape_string` is the proper way to escape data for a MySQL query. See my comment on @EdwinAlex's answer for a quote from the PHP docs.

Comment: Can you show the what `echo $query;` outputs?

Comment: It is displaying like this, or it is really saved like this in db ?

Comment: In the mysql database there is John: \ but echo's output is John: \\

Comment: Do you have any code before this that could modify post data ? And how do you collect this data ? (Show us more about your form...etc)

Comment: there isn't any code that modify post data. Now I have added the form, you can see it :)

Comment: This sounds a lot like magic_quotes at work. Not saying it will solve the whole problem but check here how to disable it: http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with PHP or MysQL.

It is as silly as very simple HTML syntax rule.
It is quite obviously that the code

```
<input value="John: "YES you can>
```

will show only quoted "John: " part. 
To make it correct, one have to encode special symbols in the value

```
$titlepost = htmlspecialchars($titlepost,ENT_QUOTES);
?>
<input type="text" name="title" value="<?=$titlepost?>">
```

As for the slashes - it is silly excessive quoting issue. just quote your strings only once and make sure you have `magic_quotes_gpc` turned off

Answer (score 0):

If you really just get `John: \` in your database, it sounds like you are using *magic quotes* (that causes you do insert backslashes in the database since you are escaping the escaped string) **and** the column size is way too small (that's why anything after the backslash is missing).

Try this:

```
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $_POST = array_map('stripslashes', $_POST);
$titlepost = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
```

This ensures that `$_POST` does not contain any magic-quotes-escaped data which would break after using `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Answer (score -1):

Try using prepared statements from PDO

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

> The parameters to prepared statements don't need to be quoted; the driver automatically handles this. If an application exclusively uses prepared statements, the developer can be sure that no SQL injection will occur (however, if other portions of the query are being built up with unescaped input, SQL injection is still possible).

Comment: Good suggeston, but it doesn't answer his question

Comment: @ThiefMaster He asks how he can save a string to the database without having problems escaping quotes. Prepared statements are a good solution.

Comment: Yes, generally they are. But even in that case you need to remove the backslashes caused by magic quotes.

Comment: True. But Magic quotes should be disabled anyway. There are deprecated as of 5.3 and removed in 5.4

Comment: You say it: *Should*  - in his system they seem to be enabled.