# What is the best field to store the birthday?

Tags: mysql

I have to store in my mysql database, the users's birthday ( like `12-11-1990` ).

What field type do I have to use to store it ?

Comment: do you mean what field type `date`

Comment: personally i love timestamps, but you should probably go with oezi's answer, MYSQL DATE are the official way to go.

Comment: Make sure you store the Locale. See my answer.

Comment: You're asking about storing a birthday with the year.  If you want to store it without the year (which is how I interpreted your question before looking at the answers, since otherwise I don't know why you're asking about birthdays specifically and not just dates in general), then just store as an integer between 1 and 366, but remember that when converting back to a date, you need to subtract 1 beginning on March 1st unless it's a leap year.

Comment: TIMESTAMP is not suitable for storing a date of birth.

The range of supported values for TIMESTAMP is '1970-01-01 00:00:01.000000' to '2038-01-19 03:14:07.999999'.

I generally suggest avoiding TIMESTAMP unless you have a good reason to choose it over DATE, TIME or DATETIME.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

to store a date, you should probably [use a date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html). to quote the documentation:

> The DATE type is used for values with a date part but no time part.

Answer (score 14):

You can store it as a `DATE` object as you would normally do with non-repeating dates. The, if you're using MySQL (I believe other DBMS also have functions for this) you can retrieve birthdays using MySQL functions as described [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE 
    MONTH(date_field) = desired_month AND 
    DAY(date_field) = desired_day
```

This method can be a bit slow when dealing with thousands of records. If that's your case, you can store the birthday with 3 separate INTs, one for each (year, month, day). Then you search birthdays like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE
   month_field = desired_month AND
   day_field = desired_day
```

If you use this last method, I'd advise you to also store a DATETIME version of the birthday so that you can build the date without any kind of maneuvers. You can additionally index each one of the 3 fields (non-unique) so it's faster to retrieve them.

Comment: Include Feb. 29th birthdays on Mar. 1st for non-leap years.

Answer (score 6):

"DATE" should be good.

> The DATE type is used for values with a date part but no time part.
>   MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. The
>   supported range is '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31'.

More details : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html

Answer (score 5):

You should store the date as DATE.

**And the Locale** as a varchar ([PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/class.locale.php) or [Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html)).

Don't forget the Locale :)

Nothing like getting an Email from something like Weibo (Chinese Twitter) when its not your birthday yet.

Answer (score 1):

is [DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/datetime.html) too obvious?

Comment: Curious how people interpreted this. I actually read it as "is it not DATE your looking for as it seems obvious?". That is @Jason may have had doubts about his answer. Consequently +1 for me to give him benefit of doubt.